# jquery find li with certain class and add another class

Tags: jquery, class, find

I'm not getting how to loop a ul and just add a class if li has class='parent'

I always get each li with my new class...

this is the code

```
$('.navigation').find('li').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('parent')) {
            $(this).find('li').each(function() {
                $(this).addClass("nivel_1");
                $(this).css('display', 'none');
                if($(".nivel_1").hasClass('parent')) {
                    $(".nivel_1").find('li').each(function() {
                        $(this).addClass("nivel_2");
                        $(this).css('display', 'none');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

this is what i get

[image: all items get nivel_1]

what should i do?

thanks!

Pluda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a tree view and those with a list within have a class called parent.

I haven't tested this (and I don't know if jQuery has something built in to do this) but you could try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navigation').find('li.parent > ul > li').addClass('nivel_X');
    $('.nivel_X').each(function(){
        var level = $(this).parents('.parent').size();
        $(this).removeClass('nivel_X').addClass('nivel_'+level);
    });
});
```

The idea is that you'll add a class to each immediant child of a li with the "parent" class and then name that class nivel_X where X is replaced by the number of parents it finds above...

The following code works too and I like it better:

```
$('.navigation').find('li.parent > ul > li').addClass(function() {
    return 'nivel_'+$(this).parents('.parent').size();
});
```

Comment: there were a few typos in there, I changed it from the one liner to have a loop in there but it works (tested it).

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton, my code was really bad compared to this one.    parent > ul > li  is the same as "search all li's wich are inside an ul inside a parent class, right?  That's the kind of things I always get lost :-)   Thank you very much.

Comment: "parent > ul > li" means the UL must be a direct descendant of the parent, and the LI must be a direct descendant of the UL.  For example if you had a DIV inside the parent with a UL inside it, then that wouldn't be captured by that selector.

Comment: As of v1.4 addClass accepts a function. I didn't notice this but I probably would have checked for the value of X instead of removing it and doing in a loop. I'll leave the code as-is because it works but I just thought I'd chime in.

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need to do a loop.  To be honest though, your code seems much more complicated than the description of your problem, so perhaps this is too simple.

```
$('li.parent').addClass("nivel_1");
```

Comment: I thought this too but if you notice his second level add nivel_2 and not nivel_1... so I think he wants a call that will add the correct depth level at the end of nivel

Comment: lol, ho boy... sometimes I feel so stupid...    just another help, and if my nivel_1 has also li.parent, how can I add nivel_2 to each?  I'm trying to make a menú with sub-items.  Thanks!

Comment: @Gazillion , yes that is exactly what I want to achieve

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML you're trying to achieve, similar to your screenshot above?

Comment: sorry not online yet, it's in my localhost joomla. Thanks for quick reply.